# Rails console overriding `~/.irbrc`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, ruby-on-rails-7

I have the following in my `~/.irbrc` file:

```
require 'irb'
require 'rubygems'
require 'awesome_print'

AwesomePrint.irb!

IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
IRB.conf[:ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT] = true
IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE] = false

# Add color coding based on Rails environment for safety

if defined? Rails
  banner = if Rails.env.production?
             "\e[41;97;1m #{Rails.env} \e[0m "
           else
             "\e[42;97;1m #{Rails.env} \e[0m "
           end

  # Build a custom prompt
  IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:CUSTOM] = IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:DEFAULT].merge(
    PROMPT_I: banner + IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:DEFAULT][:PROMPT_I]
  )

  # Use custom prompt by default
  IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :CUSTOM
end
```

In my Rails app directory, if I run `irb` then the file is sourced as shown by the disabled `:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE = false`:
[image]

However when I run `rails c`, then the file *does not* appear to be sourced; `:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE` is enabled:
[image]

Is this a load path issue or something like that?

**UPDATE** It seems it is sourcing the file but is perhaps being overridden? When I insert a deliberate error in the `~/.irbrc` file and execute `rails c` I get an error:

```
❯ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.3.1)
/Users/johnpitchko/.rbenv/versions/3.0.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/lib/irb/init.rb:336:in `load': /Users/johnpitchko/.irbrc:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the `require awesome_print` line. I disabled that and `AwesomePrint.irb!` and it worked fine.

I had the `amazing_print` gem in my `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where `rvm` was overwriting `ENV['IRBRC']` to something like `/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/.irbrc`.

There's a line in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/environment` that does `export IRBRC=`. I removed it.